# bootstrap-sass generate a too large css file which IE does not works on it

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap-sass in my project, and the generated file is larger than 288KB, which does not works in IE6 and IE7.

how to deal with this problem?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven’t seen the SASS implementation of Bootstrap, but am more familiar with the LESS version. In the bootstrap file you will notice that it does several Includes to include all the other LESS and in your case SASS files. I would first start by excluding the CSS that you don’t need from the Bootstrap. Beware some have dependencies but you can switch around items in the SASS files and repackage appropriately to handle dependencies.

Hope that helps.